# Avoid putting private fields declaration into c++ header

Tags: c#, c++, encapsulation

When I became C# lover, I was little disappointed in C++, because I believed that ancestor solves that I would call *interface problem* better than it's predecessor. The problem is, you can't get rid of **private** fields declarations inside class definition, thus encapsulation in it seems not so honest to me. For example:

```
// Righteous.h
#ifndef RIGHTEOUS_H
#define RIGHTEOUS_H
class Righteous
{
public:
    void Eat(Food* food);
    void Pray(Orison* orison);
    void Love(People* person); // by heart, not physically
private:
    void WatchHornyVideos(); // oops...
    void DoSomethingIllegal(); // hope people will never come here
    void DenyGodExistance(); // else I will probably see Him soon
}
#endif
```

Even C handles hiding implementation task better, because you can hide it's functions and fields inside `.c` files, compile them as `.lib` and deploy header and library without revealing your dirty secrets.

C# meta-class information is nice, though it's not convenient now to extract class definition using text editors like notepad or emacs. Also, C# reflection tools allow anybody to completely decompile .NET assembly, so it's not safe to deploy assemblies, even obfuscated.

In answer to this question, I'd like to see how was it solved in C++ standards from 97th to modern version.

Comment: Maybe there are different opinions on what constitutes *encapsulation*, and whether you feel that C++ provides only a fiction. What problems do you expect encapsulation to solve, and where does C++ fall short?

Comment: You would want to use the pimpl idiom which, not entirely coincidentally, makes C++ suddenly work a lot like C# (i.e. no objects are passed around, allocations are dynamic).

Comment: C does nothing with it, you can still declare free functions in the .cpp files... in C there are not even classes.

Comment: I believe his issue is that the private fields/methods of his classes are exposed in the header files, for naerdoweller's to exploit somehow (although how they would exploit it I'm not sure).

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to use private fields in class, but do not want to put them inside it's definition.

Comment: @Danatela: OK, that's just something you want. But what problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: @KerrekSB it's my curiosity again, but Callum Bradbury explained better. Actually, I wanna Righteous to look like Righteous.

Comment: @KerrekSB Secrecy. Somebody (the DoD, Apple) may want to hide implementation details.

Comment: This is an XY problem. Your actual problem is pretending C++ is C#.

Comment: Also it is a known hack to access private members with a simple `#define private public`, cf. https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=52777. Nominally UB, but that's probably the least of the problems of that code in practice.

Comment: @elyse may be... but plenty of languages influence on other languages. Such pretenders like me implemented operator overloading and class helpers in Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to further separate the interface from implementation. Abstract interface:

```
class IRighteous
{
public:
    virtual void Eat(Food* food) = 0;
    virtual void Pray(Orison* orison) = 0;
    virtual void Love(People* person) = 0;
    virtual ~IRighteous() {}
};
```

PIMPL:

```
class Righteous
{
public:
    void Eat(Food* food);
    void Pray(Orison* orison);
    void Love(People* person);

    Righteous(); // To construct RighteousImpl and assign it to the _impl.
    ~Righteous(); // Destructor needs to be defined in cpp where RighteousImpl is defined or included.
private:
    std::unique_ptr<RighteousImpl> _impl;
};
```

Comment: You'll need a `Righteous` ctor to assign a value to `_impl` since it's private ;-)

Comment: Note that for Pimpl, you should [define your own destructor](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) for `Righteous` wherever `RighteousImpl` is defined, assuming `RighteousImpl` is incomplete when the `unique_ptr` is defined (which is the point of Pimpl).

Comment: @PeterSchneider, Juraj, could you explain the both mechanisms little more verbose?

Comment: So... then you can deploy just header and binary, right?

Comment: I would make that Interface `virtual` to avoid the diamond problem.

Comment: @Danatela: Yes, and the header looks like one of the code samples above depending on the solution you choose.

Comment: @Danatela Yes. The implementation (i.e. the definition of `RighteousImpl`) is hidden. User code now cannot hold or create instances of `RighteousImpl` because its memory layout is unknown. But C++ allows to program with *pointers*  to types which are unknown; just the name must be declared, and that they have certain functions which you can call. This makes, of course, using `Righteous` inefficient, because it must dynamically allocate and free a `RighteousImpl` object. This inefficiency is the main reason (next to C compatibility) why C++ has value objects at all.

Comment: @PeterSchneider is that one of reasons of D existance? :)

Comment: @Danatela There is lots of stuff out there about the PIMPL idiom. There is also a GoW (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) discussing options. -- "D's existence": No idea :-)